# Xamarin.ios storyboard fails to open ("Something went wrong") because Main.storyboard toolsVersion keeps changing to bad version

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, storyboard

The storyboard fails to open in my VS 2019  Xamarin.ios app project on Windows.

When I change `toolsVersion="15702"` in file `Main.storyboard` to `toolsVersion="15505"` then storyboard opens.  But then it always changes back to 15702.

Comment: Hi ,do you update VS recently , which version of VS now ?